# Parse URI clicked in WebView and do something with the parameters array

Tags: java, android, parsing, uri

I am having trouble parsing the URI values of a link clicked in a WebView. I know how to get the URI that is being clicked and all that, it's just that I don't know how to parse the URI variables. Normally in java script I would have a function like this:

```
function parse_query(url){
    var qs = url.substring(url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0, result = {}; i < qs.length; i++){
        qs[i] = qs[i].split('=');
        result[qs[i][0]] = decodeURIComponent(qs[i][1]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

And I could use the parameters like this:

```
var urlArray = get_query(url);
var ProdId = urlArray['prodid'];
```

How could I write my parse_query function in android java, and then if I had a url like http://site/page?name[1]=something1&price[1]=2.00&name[2]=something2&price[2]=10.00 how could I do something with each value for the name and price arrays in the url? Maybe like...

```
each(urlArray[name]) {
print(this, price);
}
```

Or something like that, I've been awake for so many hours can't even think straight. The idea is, I want to take each name[] and corresponding price[] values and send them to a print function.